# C++ error: decomposition declaration not permitted in this context

Tags: c++, g++

Why is `g++` giving an error like this?

```
blahblah.h:80:10: error: decomposition declaration not permitted in this context
float[NUM_OUTPUTS] output_buffer;
```

(Already solved, but creating this because there's no good google hits for this error text, and the error message is inscrutable.)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's no hits on SO because this is essentially a typo. And typo Q&A's are off-topic.

Comment: Hm, it seems that the error message became **more inscrutable** with the introduction of C++17's [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: @StoryTeller  Huh, well if it costs me points but helps someone out, I'm OK with that.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah I considered specifically tagging this as C++17; but on the other hand, anyone hitting this error probably wouldn't be searching for that specific tag.  :)

Comment: I'm a bit iffy about the helpfulness as well. It'd be nice to have a hit on SO for sure. But the quality of the question isn't all that high. The code that triggered the error should not be hidden in the error message. There should be a [mcve], etc. You can make this a decent Q&A (off-topic-ness aside). Then there'd be room to discuss keeping it. Think about it from the POV of the average reviewer. It looks like a low effort solve my error for me Q. Even with your disclaimer.

Comment: Hmm, interestingly, when I try to make a one-line example I get a much more reasonable error message.  I'll have to fiddle with it for a while to figure out what the minimum code to trigger this error message actually is.  Thanks for the link to the MVCE page, I had not seen that before.

Answer (score 9):

In C++ declarations, the array size goes after the variable name, not after the type:

`float output_buffer[NUM_OUTPUTS];`